# Argument error handeling docopt python

Tags: python

Im trying to work out how to print usage info if my script isnt parsed any arguments. Im trying to achieve this with docopt. Below is the code I have and it works as expected but I just cant work out what I need to add to print the usage if no arguments are parsed or incorrect arguments. (blank argument etc) Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Description:

Compare 2 lists and print the common values.

Usage: Checker.py
  Checker.py [(-a <list1>) (-g <list2>)]
  Checker.py -h | --help
  Checker.py --version


Options:
   -a --list1         List1
   -g --list2         List2
   -h --help          Show this screen.
   --version          Show version.
"""

def getlist1(one):
    first_list = open(one).readlines()
    return [s.replace('\n', '') for s in first_list]

def getlist2(two):
    second_list = open(two).readlines()
    return [s.replace('\n', '') for s in second_list]

def checklist(list1, list2):
    return list(set(one_set) & set(two_set))    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version= '1')

    list_one = getlist1(arguments['<list1>'])
    list_two = getlist2(arguments['<list2>'])   
    found_items = checklist(list1, list2)
    found_items.sort()
    for item in found_items:
        print item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this completely answers your question, but I hope this helps.

If you run your script without any arguments, `arguments['<list1>']` and `arguments['<list2>']` both evaluate to `None`. So:

```
# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version= '1')

    if arguments['<list1>'] == None or arguments['<list2>'] == None:
        print __doc__
        exit(0)

    list_one = getlist1(arguments['<list1>'])
    list_two = getlist2(arguments['<list2>'])   
    found_items = checklist(list1, list2)
    found_items.sort()
    for item in found_items:
        print item
```

Comment: that does resolve the problem, however I thought there was some docopt magic that detected the arguments are incorrect and I just didnt have my usage formated or configured correctly?

Comment: Consider using `is None` instead of `== None` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're allowing `Checker.py` (without any arguments) as a usage pattern. Also, surounding `(-a <list1>) (-g <list2>)` with square brackets allows them to be omitted.

```
Description:

Compare 2 lists and print the common values.

Usage:
  Checker.py (-a <list1>) (-g <list2>)
  Checker.py -h | --help
  Checker.py --version


Options:
   -a --list1         List1
   -g --list2         List2
   -h --help          Show this screen.
   --version          Show version.
```

Scroll down to `(required elements)` in the [documentation](http://docopt.org) to see the case where *if one element is present, then another one is required*.

> Another use-case, is when you need to specify that if one element is
>   present, then another one is required, which you can achieve as:
>
> ```
> Usage: my_program [(<one-argument> <another-argument>)]
> ```
>
> In this case,
>   a valid program invocation could be with either no arguments, or with
>   2 arguments.

Comment: I amended my usage but get this error if supplying no arguments. `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found` id expect the usage info to print.

Comment: Huh, that is because `arguments['<list1>']` and `arguments['<list2>']` are `None`. Could you check the usage with this one again? The program works for me.

Comment: ok so there is no way for docopt to capture the error caused by the None (no arguments given) and print the usage? No problem if that is the case I just wanted to know if it was poss.

Comment: No, docopt catches the argument error and prints the usage. Check your help message with mine.